# What is so special about Klein 4-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is my first course in abstract algebra and so far I am only learning about groups. So is there anyone who can explain to me why Klein 4-group is so special that it warrants a category of its own. Please explain as clearly as possible as I am still new to algebra. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "category of its own"? It's just the name of this group. It's the smallest non-cyclic group, which is about the only interesting thing one can say about it.

Comment: meaning that it has a special name?

Comment: Are you asking why is it called the Klein four group?

Comment: How to prove that it is the smallest non-cyclic group?

Comment: nope, i know that it is just a name. Maybe there is really nothing special about it haha. Thanks

Comment: It's non-cyclic by inspection (all its non-identity elements have order 2). Any other smaller group is either trivial, and thus cyclic, or has prime order and thus cyclic by Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest anything is often of interest.  One reason is that it lets us think about why it works when nothing smaller does.  In this case, it hints that prime groups are always cyclic, and might provide a motivation to prove [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), which is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, which ordinarily wouldn't merit a special name; the alternative name for it is just a historical artifact. Klein wrote about it in 1884, though, when what would be recognizable as modern group theory was in its infancy. Cayley's wrote about groups in the 1950s; permutation groups popped around the 1870s (though Galois' work preceded it by about 40 years); Lie wrote about Lie groups in the 1880s; and so on.

Answer (score -1):

It's the **symmetry group of the rectangle**. Don't you think rectangles are important enough to warrant a category of their own?